# Roll the dice vs. Take a chance

Tags: difference, phrases

Both *roll the dice* and *take a chance* mean *test your luck*.

Is there any difference between those expressions? As far as I am aware, both phrases suppose an action to be taken; I can't imagine any difference between them.

Comment: Note that "dice" is plural and thus can't be modified by an indefinite article. It would be more common to say ["roll the dice"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/roll%20the%20dice#roll-the-dice).

Comment: Marc, [unfortunately] "dice" is nowadays accepted as singular, so we just have to live with it. (Someone took "never say die" too literally.)

Comment: @ralph.m. "Accepted" by whom?  There are some of us who still feel that saying "a dice" marks someone as an uncultured barbarian!

Comment: Regardless of whether dice can be singular, the standard idiom is still "roll the dice"

Comment: @stangdon - check what the OED says about it: "The form dice (used as plural and singular) is of much more frequent occurrence in gaming and related senses than the singular die."  So, it doesn't matter what anybody thinks about it. That's just the way it is.  Incidentally, this isn't a new thing either. The OED has the following attestation "1474   W. Caxton tr. Game & Playe of Chesse (1883) iii. viii. 152   He..caste .iii. dyse, And on eche **dyse** was a syse". The spelling is interesting, and changed shortly afterwards.

Comment: "Roll the die" never means "Take a chance". The correct expression for the purposes of this question is "Roll the **dice**."

Comment: @BillyKerr Yes, I know.  It's also of frequent occurrence for people to say "should of".  They're still ignoramuses.

Comment: @ stangdon — I agree with you entirely. This is a battle I've fought as an editor, but one I've lost each time. The dictionaries say "dice" can be plural, and that's that, it seems. (The dictionaries say it because it's too pervasive to ignore.) Sadly, the dice is cast. [Runs and hides]

Comment: Guys, it is THE dice. And it was just my typo to put A instead. @ralph.m Being barbarian is judging others for minor mistakes they make in your language, while not knowing a word from their language (or any at all).

Comment: @HexenSage Don't worry!  No one is accusing you of being a barbarian for not knowing a word in a new language.  The problem is that many *native* speakers of English still get this wrong!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Context best defines the intended meaning of an expression.

#### Roll the Dice

This expression and its variations in a neutral context, means an unpredictable (or random) outcome. It can also have a negative connotation that emphasizes risk.

1. Emphasis: Randomness

- If these candidates are equally qualified, perhaps we should choose based on a roll of the dice.

2. Emphasis: Risk

- If we don't check a candidate's references, we're simply rolling the dice.
- Every time you get on your motorcycle, you're rolling the dice.

#### Take a Chance

This expression usually emphasizes the benefits of embracing a risk, however, it is sometimes used to emphasize the risk.

1. Emphasis: Reward

- For once in your life, take a chance and ask her out!
- If you don't take a chance, you'll never know.

2. Emphasis: Risk

- Every time you cheat on a test, you're taking a chance!

**Bonus YouTube:**
[ABBA: Take A Chance On Me - (Live land '79)](https://youtu.be/9lzEG_vgato)

Comment: Thank you so much for such an amazing explanation with samples! Am I right that the key message of the *3rd* expression - "go out on a limb" is that, unlike those 2 above, it supposes NO grounds/substantiation for risk, i.e. there may be no good result at all, or things may even become worse. Is that right? (e.g., I went out on a limb climbing the rock with one broken arm).

Comment: @HexenSage My pleasure!  The example in your comment is not a good use of the expression.  Please convert your comment into [a new question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) which,  of course, I will be happy to answer.

Comment: @HexenSage, in the example, *"Every time you cheat on a test, you're taking a chance!"*, the emphasis is on the risk but there remains an implied reward from the act of cheating.  While the relative proportions of risk and reward may vary wildly, offhand, I can't think of a context where "take a chance" doesn't include at least some amount of each.